# Shut down by pressing the power button twice

Tags: windows, shutdown

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How to force a “do you really want to shutdown?” dialog in Windows 7?](https://superuser.com/questions/89894/how-to-force-a-do-you-really-want-to-shutdown-dialog-in-windows-7)

I have set my laptop's power button to shut down the computer when it is pressed (Windows 7 x86). But I often hit the button accidentally, and it's a rare case that I'm able to actually prevent it from shutting down. I don't want to disable it though.

Is there a way so that I get a confirmation whether I really want to shut down the computer (just like in Mac OS X Lion, where a confirmation appears when the power button is pressed)?.
Is there some way to bring the same to Windows 7 (and 8)?

Comment: +1. I face this prob too - I accidentally hit the power button (set to sleep) and i ve to wait for a while before it resumes. Though its a not long time to wait in my case, its still annoying.

Comment: It would be interesting to shutdown with a double press of the button. The dialog would be annoying.