# Skip Force Shutdown

Tags: windows-7, operating-systems, shutdown, administrator

When I tell my computer to shutdown it would be nice if it just skipped over the part where it says bla bla bla app is still open. I just want it to automatically force shutdown without asking me.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to force a "do you really want to shutdown?" dialog in Windows 7?](http://superuser.com/questions/89894/how-to-force-a-do-you-really-want-to-shutdown-dialog-in-windows-7)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Create a shortcut for the command `shutdown /s /f /t 000`.

Comment: The `/f` parameter for shutdown will still give you a "do you want to save"-prompt. But it will be closed automatically after 2 seconds if not answered and the shutdown will continue. (even when answering "Cancel" the shutdown will still continue !!) I think it is the closest you can get.